# What is the purpose of the pictures on the left side of the candy crush level page?

Tags: candy-crush-saga

The pictures alongside of the candy crush level page can be checked with a green check mark. What is the purpose of checking the envelopes in the heart next to the picture. Do you need to be logged into FB for this to matter?  I don't log into FB and I play on an iPad. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

on ios, they put the names into your "ask for help" list, so when you need help to get to another level or to get more lives, they are available users for you to send a message to.